# display the append data in the other viewcontroller

Tags: ios

I have two screens.
1.listing the food list
2.cart list

So in the foodlist i have cart button .So while clicking the cart button the name of the food should display in the cart list.

I have done in mvvm.

So in foodlistviewcontroller:-

```
 cell.cartaddCell = {[weak self] in
             if let i = self?.tableView.indexPath(for: $0) {

            let cartmodel:CartModel = CartModel(withoffermodel:self!.offerViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))


            let cartDataSource:ChartDataSourceModel = ChartDataSourceModel(array: nil)
            let cartViewModel:ChartViewModel = ChartViewModel(withdatasource: cartDataSource)
            cartViewModel.insertedArray = cartmodel
            print(cartViewModel.insertedArray)
            cartViewModel.add()

            let cartViewController:ChartViewController  = ChartViewController(nibName: "ChartViewController", bundle: nil, withViewModel: cartViewModel)


            self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(cartViewController, animated: true)
    // self?.present(cartViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


           // print(cartViewModel.insertedArray )


            print(cartmodel.offerdetailAddName)
            print(cartmodel)
            print(i)
           // self?.chartViewModel.delete(atIndex: i)
       }
    }
```

IN cartviewmodel:

```
  func add()  {

                datasourceModel.dataListArray?.append(insertedArray!)
                print(datasourceModel.dataListArray)
                print(insertedArray?.offerdetailAddName)

        }
```

So the name will display on the cartlist.

But when we directly click on the eventlist The name which added is not display in this screen.

So how to insert the row in this screen .

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a reloadData on the UITableView.

Perhaps a delegate from the model to the UIViewController will be a good mechanism for this.